# How to serialize a System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, serialization

Is there any way to make `System.Timers.Timer` serializable

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? Without more detail in your question about what you're trying to accomplish, I don't think it can be answered, except with "No - if it isn't already serialisable, then nothing you can do will make it so".

Comment: Why would you want to serialize a timer?

Comment: No, you can't make a non-serializable class serializable.

Comment: That's what philosophers have been trying to figure out for ages...

Comment: I have a radio player that need a timer to reload every a periode of time and I want to serialize it kos i'm using it in a web service to serialise every client data

Comment: Don't know your requirements, but maybe you could transform your timer to a custom object that is serializable (that holds enough information to reconstruct the timer), and after deserialization create a new timer based on your object.

Comment: Perhpas showing some current code can help others to point you in the right / different direction in regards to recommending a more elegant way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) attribute in [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class.

But you could make class like this (good tutorial '[Serialization (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx)'):

```
[Serializable]
public class CoolTimerWhatIWantToSerializeButForWhat
{
    public double LocalInterval { get; set; }

    public void SaveSomePropertiesOfTimer(System.Timers.Timer iWannaIt)
    {
        //save to local properties properties of iWannaIt

        LocalInterval = iWannaIt.Interval;
    }

    public System.Timers.Timer GetItBackNOW()
    {
        return new System.Timers.Timer(LocalInterval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

class Timer is not exposed as 'Serializable'.

One option would be to mark the object  as `[NonSerialized].`

Comment: I tried to do it but then the object that i want to serialize which contain the timer could not be loaded :/

Comment: define your property  timer as nonserialized and try to reload